# Solve integral by using integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I solve the following

$\int^{1+kx'-k}_{1+kx-k}(x'+k-1-ky)q(y)dy$

with $q(y)$ being an unknown probability distribution, with $y$ ranging from 0 to 1, such that one gets

$(x'+k^{2}-1-k^{2}x)q(1+kx-k)k(x'-x)$

as a result? I tried integrating by parts, and by doing that I arrived at a similarly looking solution, but I can not quite find the exact answer.

PS: This comes from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1691946/pdf/NH6HEVNU7N7NY1Q1_352_609.pdf (page 614)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what the paper says. What it says is that 
$$
\lim_{x'\to x} \frac{\int^{1+kx'-k}_{1+kx-k}(x'+k-1-ky)q(y)dy}{x'-x}=\lim_{x'\to x}\frac{(x'+k^{2}-1-k^{2}x)q(1+kx-k)k(x'-x)}{x'-x}.
$$
And what they are using is the Mean Value Theorem applied to the function $g(x)=\int_a^xf(y)\,dy$, where $f$ is continuous. You have 
$$
\int_a^xf(y)\,dy=g(x)=g(x)-g(a)=g'(c)\,(x-a)=f(c)\,(x-a). 
$$
for some $c$ between $a$ and $x$. Thus
\begin{align}
\int^{1+kx'-k}_{1+kx-k}(x'+k-1-ky)q(y)dy
&=(x'+k-1-kc)q(c)\,[(1+kx'-k)-(1+kx-k)]\\ \ \\
&=(x'+k-1-kc)q(c)\,k(x'-x).\\ \ \\
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\lim_{x'\to x}\frac{\int^{1+kx'-k}_{1+kx-k}(x'+k-1-ky)q(y)dy}{x'-x}
&=(x+k-1-k(1+kx-k))q(c)\,k\\ \ \\
&=(x+k-1-k-k^2x+k^2)q(c)\,k\\ \ \\
&=(x+k^2-1-k^2x)q(1+kx-k)\,k\\ \ \\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had never come across the MVT applied to intervals. I have one last question. Why do you substitute $c$ by $(1+kx-k)$ when computing the limit?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals). As for $q$, I'm assuming it is continuous; and $c$ is between $1+kx-k$ and $1+kx'-k$.